# Sharing the blogs data in facebook using codeigniter php

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am having blogs page which contains 5 different blogs.I need to share this particular blogs in facebook,twitter,linkedin etcc..All the blogs data is dynamic.How can we share the blogs post in social media.Here is my code

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('blogs_model');
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url('blog/index');
        $config['total_rows'] =   $this->db->count_all("blogs");//here we will count all the data from the table
        $config['per_page'] = 6;//number of data to be shown on single page
        $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data["records2"] = $this->blogs_model->get_all_blogs($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data['records7'] = $this->index_model->get_all_banners();
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();//create the link for pagination
        $data['mainpage'] = "blog";
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
```

Model:

```
function get_all_blogs($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('B.*');
    $this->db->from('blogs AS B');
    $this->db->where(array('B.status'=>1));
    $this->db->order_by("position", "asc");
    $this->db->limit('5,5');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row blogspage"> 
        <div class="col-md-12 blogpage">                
            <div class="col-md-9 blogs"> 
            <?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
            <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>          
                <div class="blog1">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/blogimages/thumbs/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" class="testimonials1"/>
                    <h3 class="heading1"><?php echo $r->blog_title;?></h3>
                    <div class="blogtext1 read">                        
                        <?php echo $r->description;?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r ->blog_id ;?>" class="read_more7" target="_blank" >Read More</a>
                </div>

            <?php endforeach ;endif;?>
            <div class="pagination"><?php echo $links; ?></div> 
            </div>
            <div class="request35">
                <?php include ("request.php");?>
            </div>

        </div>      
</div>
```

Here when ever i click on read more button the blog description will be opened in new tab and the url will be displayed in the following format

URL: http://www.staging.website.com/blog/article/2

For all the blogs there will be different ids how to share these posts in facebook

Comment: check this for sharing on facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Comment: Check this https://www.addthis.com/get/share

Comment: @BharatDangar how can we share the post based on ids there are different ids how can we right that

Comment: @BharatDangar if it is a static url we can add url but it is dynamic then how can we add this

Comment: @VinodVT how can  i share my blog based on ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make meta tag as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button and make share code

Share html code is

```
<div class="fb-share-button" 
        data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
        data-layout="button_count">
</div>
```

for data-href attribute make dynamic 
$r ->blog_id point to your post id

ex

```
<div class="fb-share-button" 
        data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r ->blog_id ;?>" 
        data-layout="button_count">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share me how to share in twitter,linkedin and gmail it will be very helpful for me

Comment: @Ashalatha It is simple Please do some Google you will get all.Try then any problem  tell.

Comment: I tried for google plus it is working fine but not able to get for linkedin and twitter

Comment: It is working fine for google plus,linkedin and all but not working for twitter it is sharing the post but the count is not displaying